# Disable specific autocomplete suggestion in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am working in a C project with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, and it is performing an automatic replacement that I can't figure out how to disable.

I have a switch statement in a function that looks something like this:

```c
A_TYPEDEF_ENUM    parameter[MAX_PARAMETERS];
uint8_t           numParams;

switch (value) {

    case optionOne:
        param[0]    = thing1;
        param[1]    = thing2;
        numParams   = 2;
        break;

     case optionTwo:
        param[0]    = thing3;
        numParams   = 1;
        break;

     default:
        /* handle error */
        break;
}
```

I'm adding some new cases to this switch statement. The problem is that as I type `numParams`, VS suggests `operator` as a candidate for autocompletion (which doesn't make sense to me since I didn't start typing "o", "p", "e", etc., but that's beside the point). Even as I complete the variable name, the suggestion is still there, so when I hit tab to insert whitespace, it replaces my variable name with `operator`.

I have seen the following questions and they don't apply, either because I don't want to completely disable autocompletion, they're trying to disable a different feature, or the languages referenced don't have the same options available  as the C/C++ projects do, in Tools -> Text Editor -> [language] -> IntelliSense/Advanced:
[How to disable undesirable auto-complete with Visual Studio + ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607024/2615940)
[Visual Studio 2013 VB intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23909559/2615940)
[How to turn off brackets/quotes auto-completion in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11055800/2615940)
[How to cancel autocomplete in Visual Studio 2015 by pressing "Space"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31570315/2615940)

**The Question**
I don't want to disable IntelliSense and autocompletion entirely, because I use it frequently. Is there a way to disable just a specific suggestion?

Comment: Hi skrrgwasme, do you mean at the begin of the switch statement, the intellisense for ‘numParams’ works fine, if you continue adding more cases under the same switch statement and this issue occurs? If so, please add a new file under this solution and test this issue again. I tried it on my xx.c file and add some ‘numParams’ code and not meet this issue.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately I haven't been able to recreate the issue. I'm not sure what was going on that day, but it hasn't occurred again. I'll keep an eye on it and post a reply here if it does again.